# Buying vegemite in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, food-and-drink, australian-citizens

[Vegemite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegemite) - love it or hate it, if you're an Aussie you'll have an opinion on it! Other countries, less so, as [the Australian Foreign Minister found out once](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/australiaandthepacific/australia/8773096/Vegemite-lands-Kevin-Rudd-in-trouble-at-US-Customs.html) when US customs couldn't believe you'd eat it for breakfast...

As an Aussie living in the UK, if you are of the "love it" persuasion, and you haven't managed to bring (enough) of it home from your last trip, where can you buy vegemite?

Comment: See [this meta question](http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/101/shopping-questions-home-comforts) for debate on if this is too specific, too much of a shopping question etc

Comment: Shouldn't there be a corresponding question about where to buy Marmite in Australia?

Comment: Quite possibly, feel free to ask it @StrongBad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you live, but it is possible to buy!

If you live in an area with lots of Australian expats, then one of your local mid sized supermarket will probably sell it. (In Oxford as an example, of the two city centre supermarkets, one stocks it)

Otherwise, try a very big supermarket, typically a large out-of-town one. You might need to ask, as sometimes it seems to get put with things like Marmite, but other times it's in an "ethnic foods" section, and some times it's just random...

Since it isn't something that is available everywhere, but is available, you might need to ask other expats for advice for where to go. Otherwise just try traipsing around a few supermarkets and ask!

Answer (score 5):

Vegemite can be found in most UK supermarkets. It can also be purchased online in the UK from MySupermarket, among others.

It's well known enough in the UK to warrant an [article on the spread of vegemite in the BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-19908368).

In London, the Aussie/NZ/Saffa store in Covent Garden used to sell it - presume they still do (this was only a few years back), albeit with a substantial markup.

Not only is it available in Tesco, Asda, Waitrose AND Sainsburys, it's actually sold [cheaper than it is in Australia](http://www.news.com.au/finance/money/vegemite-is-cheaper-overseas-than-in-australia/story-fnagkbpv-1226576999305)!

[Here it is on the Tescos site](http://www.tesco.com/groceries/product/details/?id=263013202) and on [MySupermarket](http://www.mysupermarket.co.uk/tesco-price-comparison/jam_and_spreads/kraft_vegemite_220g.html) as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the Aussie/NZ/Saffa store has now closed down.  You can also now get cherry ripes, twisties & more Aussie tucker from Ocado